# save Array of strings to core data and retrieve it. iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, core-data

Is it possible to save an attribute of an array of strings into core data and then retrieve array?

I am saving data to core data and retrieving some of it shown in the prints below.

Here is my save data function..

```
func saveToCoreData(completion: (_ finished: Bool) -> ()) {
    guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else { return }
    let saveTrip = SavedTrips(context: managedContext)



    saveTrip.desc = tripDescription
    saveTrip.name = tripName
    saveTrip.data = ["12345"]
    let time = Time()
    time.date = Date()
    saveTrip.date = time.date

    do {
    try managedContext.save()
        completion(true)

        print("Successfuly Saved to core Data")
    }catch {
        debugPrint("Tony: Could not save \(error.localizedDescription)")
        completion(false)
    }
}
```

And my tripCell where I am calling the data.

```
class TripsCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tripName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tripDescription: UILabel!




func configureCell(savedTrip: SavedTrips) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium
    self.tripName.text = savedTrip.name
    self.tripDescription.text = savedTrip.desc
    print("Tony: trip name: \(savedTrip.name!)")
    print("Tony: trip description: \(savedTrip.desc!)")
    if let tripData = savedTrip.data {
        print("Tony Calling Plates: \(tripData)")

    }else {
        print("Tony: There is no trip Data")
    }
    if let date = savedTrip.date {
        let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
        dateFormater.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
        dateLabel.text = dateFormater.string(from: date)
    }
}
}
```

My core Data Model...
[image: My Core Data model]

and my printout.Showing nothing in the array.

[image]

Comment: Are you by any chance working with UIAlertViewController? Sometimes I get this error if I try to dismiss one controller and then display another one immediately. If this is the case make sure you are showing the second controller in the completion handler of the first controller.

Comment: Hi no, I am overwriting the animation of present view controller

Comment: I’m calling present from table cell did select